# dplyr::mutate_at behaves like mutate when fed a single variable

Tags: r, dplyr

When I feed a single variable to mutate_at, it seems to regress to mutate, as the following code shows. Is this a bug or am I doing it wrong?

```
library("tidyverse")
x <- data_frame("a" = 1:3, "b" = 4:6)
f <- function(y){2L * y}

x %>% mutate_at(vars(c("a", "b")), funs(x = f))

x %>% mutate_at(c("a"),            funs(x = f))
x %>% mutate_at(vars(c("a")),      funs(x = f))
x %>% mutate_at(vars(c("a", "a")), funs(x = f))
x %>% mutate_at(c("a", "a"),       funs(x = f))
```

Comment: That's feature of `mutate_at`. It applies function on list of variable just to avoid writing multiple `mutate`(one for each variable). If you provide only one variable it will act as `mutate`.

Comment: I use `mutate_at` within a function and cannot predict the length of the arguments that will be passed through to `mutate_at`. This inconsistent behaviour is a minefield.

Comment: I agree with you this is confusing, one does not know necessarily if one or two inputs! I asked the question on github: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/4356

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug, this is part of how `mutate_at` works. From the help file:

> By default, the newly created columns have the shortest names needed to uniquely identify the output. To force inclusion of a name, even when not needed, name the input (see examples for details).

```
smalliris <- select(iris, ends_with("Length"))

smalliris %>% head

# Sepal.Length Petal.Length
# 1          5.1          1.4
# 2          4.9          1.4
# 3          4.7          1.3
# 4          4.6          1.5
# 5          5.0          1.4
# 6          5.4          1.7

smalliris %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with("Length")), funs(sd)) %>% head

# Sepal.Length Petal.Length
# 1    0.8280661     1.765298
# 2    0.8280661     1.765298
# 3    0.8280661     1.765298
# 4    0.8280661     1.765298
# 5    0.8280661     1.765298
# 6    0.8280661     1.765298

smalliris %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with("Length")), funs(sd, var)) %>% head

# Sepal.Length Petal.Length Sepal.Length_sd Petal.Length_sd Sepal.Length_var Petal.Length_var
# 1          5.1          1.4       0.8280661        1.765298        0.6856935         3.116278
# 2          4.9          1.4       0.8280661        1.765298        0.6856935         3.116278
# 3          4.7          1.3       0.8280661        1.765298        0.6856935         3.116278
# 4          4.6          1.5       0.8280661        1.765298        0.6856935         3.116278
# 5          5.0          1.4       0.8280661        1.765298        0.6856935         3.116278
# 6          5.4          1.7       0.8280661        1.765298        0.6856935         3.116278

smalliris %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(ends_with("Length")), funs(myname = sd)) %>% head

# Sepal.Length Petal.Length Sepal.Length_myname Petal.Length_myname
# 1          5.1          1.4           0.8280661            1.765298
# 2          4.9          1.4           0.8280661            1.765298
# 3          4.7          1.3           0.8280661            1.765298
# 4          4.6          1.5           0.8280661            1.765298
# 5          5.0          1.4           0.8280661            1.765298
# 6          5.4          1.7           0.8280661            1.765298
```

Comment: I don't think you r example is covering the OP's case, where input function might be of length 1, and functions are named?

Comment: What do you mean? That’s what’s happening in the last example.

Comment: By naming a function I mean having `funs(x =sd)` as in your example. Also, OP's issue happens when there is only one input variable, which does not seem to be the case in your example?

Answer (score 0):

I asked the question on the github, and a nice answer was given:

- manually: should just make sure the vector of columns is named, i.e. `c(a="a")`
- with helpers: use `tidyselect::vars_select`

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
x <- tibble("a" = 1:3, "b" = 4:6)
f <- function(y){2L * y}

## The problem:
x %>% mutate_at(vars(c("a")), list(x = f))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       a     b     x
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     4     2
#> 2     2     5     4
#> 3     3     6     6

# manual solution
x %>% mutate_at(c(a = "a"), list(x = f))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       a     b   a_x
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     4     2
#> 2     2     5     4
#> 3     3     6     6

# solution using helpers:
x %>% mutate_at(tidyselect::vars_select(names(.), contains("a")), list(x = f))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>       a     b   a_x
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     4     2
#> 2     2     5     4
#> 3     3     6     6
```